# I am not able to change state using set state in componentDidMount

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am not able to change the state after getting response from an axios get request

This is for a simple login/signup page using MERN stack where  I am trying to get to users personalized page only after authorizing him on the node.js backend.
I have tried the method which is common by using _ismounted but after some debugging I saw that the componentWillMount method is being called right after axios get which then makes the _isMounted as false hence does not go inside the if code where i am using setState

```
class User extends Component {
    _isMounted = false;

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state={
            isAuthenticated:false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this._isMounted = true;
        const token=localStorage.getItem("token");
        //alert(token);
        axios
        .get(`https://localhost:3443/users/${this.props.user}`,{ headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } })
        .then(res => {
            if (this._isMounted){
            this.setState(() => ({
                isAuthenticated:true
              }));
            }
        })
        .catch(err => alert(JSON.stringify(err)));
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
      }

    render() {
        if(this.state.isAuthenticated===false) return(<Redirect to="/home" />)
        return(
            <div>
                Hello {this.props.user}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I just want to perform axios get before page is rendered to check if the user is authorized or not and accordingly change state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never reached the `componentDidMount` lifecycle since in your `render` function you are checking if the `isAuthenticated` is false and doing a redirect.

As you have set the initial value of `isAuthenticated` as `false`, it always redirect to `/home` and calls the `componentWillUnmount`.

> This is because `componentDidMount` run after the first `render` is done.

To solve this, you can set the initial value of `isAuthenticated` as `null` so your component will reach the `componentDidMount` and perform the axios call to verify if the user is authenticated or not.

```
this.state = { isAuthenticated:null };
```

Answer (score 0):

change your render function like this.. i think it might help for you..

```
render(){
     return (
     <div>
      {
           this.state.isAuthenticated === false ? (
                      <Redirect to="/home" />
           ):(
                      <div>{this.props.user}</div>
              )
       }
      </div>
      )
}
```